# Transfer "Would you mind if..." into indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

Direct speech: **"Would you mind if I gave you a brief instruction, Jason?" said Chloe.**

--> Chloe told......

Someone wrote: **Chloe told Jason to give him a brief instruction.**

It sounds very odd to me. In addition, I also have no idea how to construct a proper indirect speech out of it.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: btw, can i write: Chloe told Jason to let her give him a brief instruction. Would it sound natural?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the original sounds a bit weird to a native English speaker. We tend to use "an instruction" to mean one explicit command or order. It sounds odd to ask someone if you can command them to do something. It also sounds odd to say that a single command would be brief. More verbose, written details on carrying out a task are referred to as "instructions", but again, it doesn't seem natural to ask permission to impart these verbally.

We do use "instruction" as a noun with zero article to mean training. Perhaps this is the intended meaning?

Also, Chloe is asking Jason a question, so we would say she 'asked', rather than 'said' it.

I would guess the intended meaning was that they were asking if they had sufficient time to go through the details of a specific task, on the understanding that it would be "brief". I would probably say:

> "Would you mind if I **briefly** gave you **some instruction**, Jason?" **asked** Chloe.

This could be abbreviated to:

> Chloe asked Jason if she could briefly give him some instruction.

or

> Chloe offered to give Jason some brief instruction.